# AWS Lambda function to launch Glue job

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-glue

I don't have much idea about AWS lambda. My requirement is to run Glue job once file is copied to S3 bucket.

So I am planing to launch AWS Glue job using AWS Lamdba. But Lambda function has limit of 300ms and my Glue job will take hours.

My question is how Lambda will work, Will it launch Glue job and exit. Or if we kill lambda job Glue job will also get killed?

If we kill lambda job and glue job also killed. then what is other solution?

Comment: Hi,  I have a similar requirement, to launch an AWS Glue job, from AWS Lambda (the lambda function initially copies files from one bucket to another bucket).  On successful copying of files, I would like to call/launch a glue job, which is already available.  Appreciate if you can please provide some sample code.

Comment: did you solve it? I also have that problem @Yuva

Comment: I solved it like this `AWSGlue awsGlueClient = AWSGlueClient.builder().withRegion("us-east-1").build();
    StartJobRunRequest jobRunRequest = new StartJobRunRequest();
    jobRunRequest.setJobName("my_transformer");
    StartJobRunResult jobRunResult = 
    awsGlueClient.startJobRun(jobRunRequest);` `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-glue</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.826</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 6):

Daniel

The following worked for me, and is on production for last 2 years.  Am giving below python code sample only for invoking a glue job from AWS Lambda.

Thanks

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import urllib

print('Loading function')

glue = boto3.client('glue')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    gluejobname="GLUE_JOB_NAME"

    try:
        runId = glue.start_job_run(JobName=gluejobname)
        status = glue.get_job_run(JobName=gluejobname, RunId=runId['JobRunId'])
        print("Job Status : ", status['JobRun']['JobRunState'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    raise e
```

Comment: Hi I'm using this method to use a Lambda to invoke the glue job, but job failed, however if I kick off the job from Glue console directly it will succeed, I posted the error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66139965/use-stepfunction-to-start-a-glue-job-error-failing-this-attempt-diagnostics-ex

Answer (score 2):

Lambda will kick of the glue trigger and exit. The Glue job will keep on running.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Glue job will continue running since the call from AWS Lambda is asynchronous.

Using Lambda Python handler with [Boto AWS Python SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) you will run the Glue job (actually a REST API call) while the Lambda function exits.

See more details here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html

Comment: Hi, I have a similar requirement, to launch an AWS Glue job, from AWS Lambda JAVA (the lambda function initially copies files from one bucket to another bucket). On successful copying of files, I would like to call/launch a glue job, which is already available. Appreciate if you can please provide some sample code

Answer (score 0):

`

```
AWSGlue awsGlueClient = AWSGlueClient.builder().withRegion("us-east-1").build();
StartJobRunRequest jobRunRequest = new StartJobRunRequest();
jobRunRequest.setJobName("my_transformer");
StartJobRunResult jobRunResult = awsGlueClient.startJobRun(jobRunRequest);
```

`

`

```
<dependency>     
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>     
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk-glue</artifactId>     
<version>1.11.826</version> 
</dependency>
```

`