# Retirgger aws glue job dynamically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, batch-processing, jobs

I am trying to configure an aws glue job with spark as executive engine. I want to understand what are different ways to be notified on the job status, assume I need to get a notification on both success and failure states of the job. Because based on the output of the job , I need to publish a kafka event. And what if the job failed due to some network issue, how can I restart the job after some time dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can create alert notification using Amazon EventBridge as shown in [here](https://medium.com/@ureniucbogdan/unleash-the-power-of-alerts-keeping-your-finger-on-the-pulse-of-aws-glue-scripts-72640f389be7) and instead of Email alert, you can link a lambda function that can run a glue job.([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63096082/9836179)).